# Subscribe to "current" component's destroy event

Tags: angular

I'm trying to subscribe to the a components destroy event. Component A is creating Component B dynamically and inserting it outside of Component As DOM. I would like to subscribe to the destory event so I can remove the created component.

ComponentRef has a handy onDestroy method but I cannot find a way to get a reference to the ComponentRef that represents Component A (which was created conventionally).

I could pass in an emitter, implement onDestroy in Component A and emit to it on destroy and react to that but that seems quite fiddly and annoying to have to do over and over.

Edit:

I ended up coming at this from a different angle. I wrote a component to act as something of an intermediary using is own ViewContainerRef to clean up things.

```
import {
  ApplicationRef, Component, ContentChild, ContentChildren, EmbeddedViewRef, OnDestroy,
  QueryList,
  TemplateRef, ViewChild,
  ViewContainerRef, ViewEncapsulation
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnDestroy {
  @ContentChild('title') title: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ContentChild('body') body: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ContentChildren('button') buttons: QueryList<TemplateRef<any>>;
  @ViewChild(TemplateRef) modaltemplate;
  views: EmbeddedViewRef<any>[] = [];

  constructor(private appRef: ApplicationRef, private vcRef: ViewContainerRef) {
  }

  show (context) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const modalView = this.vcRef.createEmbeddedView(this.modaltemplate);
      const modalTitleView = this.vcRef.createEmbeddedView(this.title, {$implicit: context});
      const modalBodyView = this.vcRef.createEmbeddedView(this.body, {$implicit: context});
      const modalElement = modalView.rootNodes[0];

      this.views.push(modalView, modalTitleView, modalBodyView);

      const titleElement = modalElement.querySelector('.modal-card-title');
      const bodyElement = modalElement.querySelector('.modal-card-body');
      const buttonsElement = modalElement.querySelector('.buttons');

      modalTitleView.rootNodes.forEach(c => {
        titleElement.appendChild(c);
      });

      modalBodyView.rootNodes.forEach(c => {
        bodyElement.appendChild(c);
      });

      this.buttons.forEach(b => {
        const buttonView = this.vcRef.createEmbeddedView(b, {$implicit: context});

        buttonView.rootNodes.forEach(n => {
          if (n.classList.contains('cancel')) {
            n.addEventListener('click', () => this.hide());
          }
          buttonsElement.appendChild(n);
        });
        this.views.push(buttonView);
      });

      document.body.appendChild(modalElement);
    }, 0);
  }

  hide () {
    this.views.splice(0, this.views.length)
      .forEach(v => {
        v.destroy();
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.views.splice(0, this.views.length)
      .forEach(v => {
        v.destroy();
      });
  }
}
```

usage:

```
<app-modal #deleteModal>
  <ng-template #title let-data>Are you sure you want to unassign {{data.profile.name}} from {{data.place.name}} {{data.place.shortDescription}}?</ng-template>
  <ng-template #body>Don't worry, you can always reassign them back later.</ng-template>
  <ng-template #button let-data><button class="button is-info" (click)="data.removeStaff(data.place, data.profile)">Unassign Staff</button></ng-template>
  <ng-template #button><button class="button cancel">Cancel</button></ng-template>
</app-modal>
```

Comment: Can't you  keep the track of created components  in local list and dispose these components when component A destroyed?

Comment: nayakam has the right idea. You *should not ever* place a child component out of the scope of its parent. Have the top most common parent create and manage the component. If you need, pass data from Component A up the tree first, then have the top most node make and place.

Comment: @Z.Bagley, so how would you implement a modal dialog with a parent having `overflow:hidden` if not placing it outside the parent?

Comment: I don't really understand why you need a reference to the AComponent. Just implement `ngOnDestroy` on the AComponent class and remote BComponent from it

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com I'd have root manage the dialog component like I always do, and follows the Material implementation guidelines

Comment: @Z.Bagley, what is `root`?

Comment: The root module, top-most node in an app

Comment: @Z.Bagley, root component? So if a child component wants to create a modal, it triggers an event on some service shared with the root component and it shows the modal as its child?

Comment: That's exactly how I normally handle this, yep

Comment: I wanted to avoid having ComponentA having to implement lifecycle wiring for ComponentB. ComponentB is used in several places.

Comment: I've observed you can create a component using your local `ViewContainerRef` then move that components rootNodes somewhere else (like as a child of body). As long as you call destroy on the ref the node is still removed - this seems to decouple lifecycle from dom hierachy.

Comment: I guess I ultimately did ended up maintaining a list of components to destroy, just not in a way that has me doing it per use.

Comment: @Z.Bagley, okay, then how does libraries like material or bootstrap achieve that when they don't control your root component?

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview And the dialog component is required to be imported into your root module, it manages the viewcontainer refs and such.

Comment: @Z.Bagley, the dialog uses [portals mechanism](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/c7de734cd0d07ccfa67e1148864fc48e09c422c9/src/lib/dialog/dialog.ts#L248), and portals [create components outside of component elements](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/45624077c6de4b525a61142c1d3c7290c96f5eb4/src/cdk/portal/dom-portal-host.ts#L63).

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com Through the root... which is why it's imported into the root module. All I'm saying is a lot of changes where made with material to enforce a top module structure for DOM management. If a component is created it should always be in scope of the parent, and Angular 2+ as well as Material 2 follow this practice.

Comment: @Z.Bagley, check [this example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/emgagvlolxy?file=index.html). The dialog is rendered outside root `DialogOverviewExample` component

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com You keep saying component, and I'm referring the to Module that handles that Component. I keep saying module on purpose to make that distinction.

Comment: @Z.Bagley, okay, but modules don't exist in runtime, read [Avoiding common confusions with modules in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/avoiding-common-confusions-with-modules-in-angular-ada070e6891f)